# Android Studio Weather Application Crashing

Tags: java, android, api, mobile, weather

So, I have been following a YouTube tutorial for an android Weather application. The app seems to compile, however crashes whenever opened on the emulator. I'm not the most fluent programmer, however the code is understood. I can't figure out what's causing the issue though. The app is supposed to fetch weather data for the location of the hardcoded location in "MainActivity.java". The data is fetched from Yahoo! using an API.

Link for the project files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2dQ9-JQjysVeXlqZENBZDExN0E?usp=sharing

Below is the error I get:

> --------- beginning of crash
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.mattbenson.cw_2_weather, PID: 2529
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.optInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.mattbenson.cw_2_weather.service.WeatherService$1.onPostExecute(WeatherService.java:81)
>                         at com.example.mattbenson.cw_2_weather.service.WeatherService$1.onPostExecute(WeatherService.java:38)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
>   E/EGL_emulation: tid 2570: swapBuffers(487): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: swapBuffers encountered EGL error 12301 on 0x76990bb1c580, halting rendering...
>   Application terminated.

(Sorry, I am new to this site!)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As StackTrace says the error is at Class `WeatherService` at line 81 `int count = queryResults.optInt("Count");` because it is returning **NULL**.

Try using method [optInt with fallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) value `queryResults.optInt("Count", 0);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've changed the statement, however the app still crashes. This is the error I get: 
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.optInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.mattbenson.cw_2_weather.service.WeatherService$1.onPostExecute(WeatherService.java:81)
                      at com.example.mattbenson.cw_2_weather.service.WeatherService$1.onPostExecute(WeatherService.java:38)